# Power Automate: Loop through SELECT

Tags: flow, power-automate, loop

I want to send a personalized email with additional infos to hundreds of employees. The informations are stored in a massive Excel file.
My goal is to create a Flow which runs every morning, filters the list by the actual date and sends the email to the filtered employees. For every send email there should be a cell filled behind the employees name with the text 'success' (or whatever).

I know that looping through an Excel file is quiet time consuming so my idea was to store the data in a SELECT object and loop it from there. I managed to set up the flow to store the data inside the SELECT but how do I loop throught it AND transfer the success message to the Excel sheet?

*My Flow so far:*

[image]

**EDIT:**

I created an "Apply to each" loop for the SELECT action, which gives me every "line" with the corresponding entry:
[image]

I'm still struggeling to access these entries (for example *Select_Email* ) with some syntax to pass the Email-adress to a mail connector.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to access the data with dynamic expressions in a *Apply to each* loop with the SELECT as source:
[image]

To access a specific field in the current item, I used

`item()?['Select_Email']`

OR

`@{items('Auf_alle_anwenden')?['Select_Email']}`

to get (in this case) the email address.